# Highlight immediate cells after conditional formatting rule is satisfied

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column which looks like this -

| Col1 |
| --- |
| A |
| B |
| C |
| A |
| D |
| V |
| A |
| X |

My first conditional formatting is to highlight all the cells where Col1 contains "A".

But I also want that **after all the A cells have been highlighted it should highlight the next immediate cell after A no matter what the value is**.

How to go about that?

Edit 01 -

Unable to figure out what am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: For your 'green rule' you need to change the change the range for which you have defined the formatting to be from `A2:A11`, and amend the test to be `=$A1="A"` so that the referenced cell is the one _before_ the start of your range

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 1st rule below applies conditional formatting if the current cell contains `A`

[image: Screenshot illustrating proposed solution]

and the 2nd applies conditional formatting if the preceding cell contains `A`.

Comment: This is formatting the cell above A and not below, I would like to format the below one.

Comment: @Maxima the screenshot clearly shows that the cells _below_ those containing `A` have been highlighted

Comment: I just tried replicating this and it is working opposite, all the cells above A have been highlighted. Can I edit my question and share the ss?

Comment: @Maxima yes, of course, you can edit your question - the key with conditional formatting, though, is always to have the '$` references correct vs the range for which you have defined the formatting